# How to enforce calling super in overridden method

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can I enforce calling `[super methodName...]` in an overridden method?

Besides stating it in comments, is there another way, perhaps a trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark the method using the [`objc_required_super` attribute](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#objc-requires-super):

```
- (void)foo __attribute__((objc_requires_super));
```

This way the compiler will emit a warning if the user doesn't call `super`. But apart from that warning, there is no way to really *enforce* it.

AFAIK, only in `dealloc` (when using ARC) does the compiler enforce calling `super`. And it does it by forbidding you to call it yourself, so it can always safely inject the `super` call.

Comment: very handy! there is also a macro for it NS_REQUIRES_SUPER